# @SuppressLit(({"ParseError","ParseError"})

Tags: android

I am a newbie on android development. I want to know that when i try to remove errors, a line appears in my code, that is:

```
@SuppressLint({ "ParserError", "ParserError", "ParserError", "ParserError", "ParserError", "ParserError", "ParserError", "ParserError", "ParserError" }) @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Thread timer = new Thread(){
        @SuppressLint("ParserError") public void run(){
            try{
                sleep(5000);
            }
            catch(InterruptedException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            finally{
                Intent intent = new Intent("com.example.basiccounter.COUNTER");
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
    };
    timer.start();
}
```

}

I want to know that what @SuppressLint({}) line of code means and why this happens? and how to overcome with this problem?

Comment: can you please post your code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have the same issue. It's the new updated Lint parser for android having some problems. I must say it has a few bugs when you are copy-pasting a lot of lines or updating without saving frequently.

In order to overcome this problem, I don't add these warnings and I simply cut the "problematic" lines according to Lint, save so as not to have build errors and then repasting and the warning is gone. I can't find a pattern to this problem nor I have a standard solution. I guess it should work on you to. Give it a try

UPDATED:
I have found a new solution that does not involve copy pasting code. If you are ALMOST CERTAIN that your code is correct and there should not be a Lint marker there just click the warning button and select "clear all lint markers". Then built and you are good to go.

If the problem persists then the lint marker is indeed somehow useful and it is not a bug.

Answer (score 1):

There is an issue opened about the problem on the ADT's bug tracker : [Here](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=lint%20parse&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars&groupby=&sort=&id=34307)

Star it or add interesting information on comments if you have.

Answer (score 1):

Annotations are a manner in which you can add meta-data to your code. For instance that a methods shouldn't be used anymore (`@Deprecated`). You could see annotations as a kind of flag with information. Another program can spot those flag and perform logic based on that. For instance annotations are heavily used for `ORM` with `JPA` to create a database model.